# How to link_to user profile from different MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can we list out the user's name who submitted the habit: `<%= link_to @habit.user.name, @user %>`, but upon clicking on it the user is redirected back to the show page: http://0.0.0.0:3000/habits/1 instead of being redirected to the user's profile page: http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1?

**habits_controller**

```
  def show
    @notable = @habit
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    @commentable = @habit
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @correct_user = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :habits
  end

  resources :habits do
    resources :notes
    resources :notifications
    resources :comments do
      resources :likes
    end
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
    resources :levels do
      # we'll use this route to increment and decrement the missed days
      resources :days_missed, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the link url to be more specific?
I.e. `<%= link_to @habit.user.name, user_path(@habit.user) %>`

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `@user` as the second parameter of the `link_to` method call, Rails is inferring the user_path route. Instead of `@user`, you should be able to pass `@habit` and see the appropriate behavior.

If the implicit path argument doesn't work, you could more specifically pass `habit_path(@habit.id)`

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the explanation but I think one of us is reading the other wrong. Elle's answer works. The goal was to `link_to` the user's profile. `@user`, `@habit`, & `habit_path(@habit.id)` takes the user back to the show page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your @user instance is not defined correctly. What you defined as @user is actually habit instance.